# Wifi-Disabled: Ubuntu 16.04 - Intel Wireless 7265

Tags: 14.04, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

It's a fresh Install. There is no Hardware Switch to Turn it On or Off.
It was working before on 16.04. Had to reinstall due to F***up dpkg and now it's not working. Tried everything from the net, loading firmware from official intel linux. still no way out.

```
$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`phy1` is my usb wifi dongle (Currently using it to post to net):

```
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b0:5a:da:ab:b3:27  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1407 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1407 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:124686 (124.6 KB)  TX bytes:124686 (124.6 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

virbr0-nic Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:b0:b2:13  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 94:65:9c:9a:28:65  
          inet addr:192.168.0.106  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6944:3c7b:ebe8:127f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:68 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:61 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:13696 (13.6 KB)  TX bytes:8894 (8.8 KB)

wlx14cc2016d4a9 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 14:cc:20:16:d4:a9  
          inet addr:192.168.0.105  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c040:c2f3:37a8:191a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:416 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:449 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:124672 (124.6 KB)  TX bytes:68949 (68.9 KB)<br>
```

`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 61)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

`ls -al /lib/firmware | grep 7265`:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  736844 Dec  2 02:24 iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  880604 Dec  2 02:24 iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  885224 Dec  2 02:24 iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1180356 Mar 14 10:54 iwlwifi-7265-16.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1180412 Dec 10 02:17 iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  690452 Apr 25  2016 iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  697828 Dec  2 02:24 iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      21 Mar  9 00:59 iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode -> iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1002800 Dec  2 02:24 iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1008692 Dec  2 02:24 iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1384500 Mar 14 10:54 iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1383604 Dec 10 02:17 iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1385368 Dec 10 02:17 iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1028316 Dec 10 02:17 iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode
```

`lshw -c network`:

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 61
       serial: 94:65:9c:9a:28:65
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-41-generic firmware=22.361476.0 ip=192.168.0.106 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:284 memory:b1500000-b1501fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 15
       serial: b0:5a:da:ab:b3:27
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:281 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1404000-b1404fff memory:b1400000-b1403fff
  *-network:0 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:b0:b2:13
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
  *-network:1
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 4
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: wlx14cc2016d4a9
       serial: 14:cc:20:16:d4:a9
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k_htc driverversion=4.8.0-41-generic firmware=1.4 ip=192.168.0.105 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Thanking in advance.

Comment: yep. i tried. but it said wait for 7 mins. so i added solved, so that others don't waste time on giving answer to already solved problem :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"
```

and reboot. This will remove the block.